# How to iterate over the elements of a map in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, iteration

Given a string `s`, I want to know how many times each character at the string occurs. Here is the code:

```
def main() :
  while True :
    try :
      line=raw_input('Enter a string: ')
    except EOFError :
      break;
    mp={};

    for i in range(len(line)) :
      if line[i] in mp :
        mp[line[i]] += 1;
      else :
        mp[line[i]] = 1;

    for i in range(len(line)) :
      print line[i],': ',mp[line[i]];

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  main();
```

When I run this code and I enter `abbba`, I get:

```
a : 2
b : 3
b : 3
b : 3
a : 2
```

I would like to get only:

```
a : 2
b : 3
```

I understand why this is happening, but as I'm new to python, I don't know any other ways to iterate over the elements of a map. Could anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try a Counter (Python 2.7 and above; see below for a pre-2.7 option):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('abbba')
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2})
```

You can then access the elements just like a dictionary:

```
>>> counts = Counter('abbba')
>>> counts['a']
2
>>> counts['b']
3
```

And to iterate, you can use @BurhanKhalid's suggestion (the `Counter` behaves as a dictionary, where you can iterate over the key/value pairs):

```
>>> for k, v in Counter('abbba').iteritems():
...   print k, v
...
a 2
b 3
```

If you're using a pre-2.7 version of Python, you can use a `defaultdict` to simplify your code a bit (process is still the same - only difference is that now you don't have to check for the key first - it will 'default' to 0 if a matching key isn't found). `Counter` has other features built into it, but if you simply want counts (and don't care about `most_common`, or being able to `subtract`, for instance), this should be fine and can be treated just as any other dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> counts = defaultdict(int)
>>> for c in 'abbba':
...   counts[c] += 1
...
>>> counts
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'b': 3})
```

When you use `iteritems()` on a dictionary (or the `Counter`/`defaultdict` here), a key and a value are returned for each iteration (in this case, the key being the letter and the value being the number of occurrences). One thing to note about using dictionaries is that they are inherently unordered, so you won't necessarily get `'a', 'b', ...` while iterating. One basic way to iterate through a dictionary in a sorted manner would be to iterate through a sorted list of the keys (here alphabetical, but `sorted` can be manipulated to handle a variety of options), and return the dictionary value for that key (there are other ways, but this will hopefully be somewhat informative):

```
>>> mapping = {'some': 2, 'example': 3, 'words': 5}
>>> mapping
{'some': 2, 'example': 3, 'words': 5}
>>> for key in sorted(mapping.keys()):
...   print key, mapping[key]
...
example 3
some 2
words 5
```

Comment: Nice answer, but could you tell me how to iterate over the elements of the counter?

Comment: `for k, v in Counter('aaaabbbcccddd').iteritems():`

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Sure thing (Ignacio's post below shows the most straightforward way).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid's is pretty sweet as well :)

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: `.iteritems()` saves you the additional dictionary lookup on every iteration

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Added a little more context (that on second thought was probably all in the link provided by Ignacio :) ), but hopefully it will clear things up a bit more.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes I noticed another question you posted about upgrading to Python 2.7 that seemed to be related to `Counter`. I definitely agree with upgrading, but I dropped in an update (using `defaultdict`, which is also mentioned by Michael below) that you can use in 2.6 if you'd like.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes Ha, no worries - just wanted to add some more information to flesh it out a bit. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 8):

Iterating over a [**mapping**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) yields keys.

```
>>> d = {'foo': 42, 'bar': 'quux'}
>>> for k in d:
...   print k, d[k]
... 
foo 42
bar quux
```

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: Since `collections.Counter` is a mapping you can iterate over one in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look up the help for dict(). It's all there -- 'for k in mp' iterates over keys, 'for v in mp.values()' iterates over values, 'for k,v in mp.items()' iterates over key, value pairs.

Also, you don't need those semicolons. While they are legal in Python, nobody uses them, there's pretty much no reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.5 and above

```
  dDIct = collections.defaultdict(int)
  [(d[i]+=1) for i in line]
  print dDict
```

Comment: I believe you meant `collections.defaultdict` :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey: Yes you right, it happens when you use your smartphone ;-)